# Accessing another's instance private field of the same class in Java and Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

Assume that we have such piece of code in Java:

```
abstract class A {
    private int x = 1;
    public void smth(A a) {
        a.x = 2;
    }
    public void print() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}

class B extends A {}

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        B b1 = new B(), b2 = new B();
        b2.smth(b1);
        b1.print();
        b2.print();
    }
}
```

This code compiles and outputs `1 2`, as expected.
However, when we compile an analogous piece of code in Groovy, it throws a `groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException`:

```
class A {
    private int x = 1;
    void smth (A a) {
        a.x = 2
    }
    void print() {println x}
}

class B extends A {}

B b1 = new B(), b2 = new B()
b2.smth(b1)
b1.print()
b2.print()
```

So the question is: can we access a private field of another instance of the came class in Groovy as we do in analogous Java code, and how?

Comment: Though that is about closures, and this is about different instances of the same superclass :-/

Comment: Yes, a similar solution can be applied to this problem by changing `x` field's access level from private to protected.